# If a date column doesn't have a certain date, then do something

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read from dataframe on `Date` column, if a certain date doesn't exist, then insert new data for that date.

I've tried to googled on how to know if a return is none, but I can't find any result.

So this is the way I handle it, if the return is `KeyError`, then I insert the date data. But my concern is, what if the `KeyError` is NOT because the data doesn't exist?

Or is there any better way than catching a KeyError like this?

My Code

```
def checkdata(ticker, date):
    try: 
        data = pd.read_sql(ticker, idxengine)
        data = data.set_index('Date')
        data.loc[date]
        print(data.loc[date])
    except KeyError as ke:
        print("Data not found, insert new date data" + ticker + str(date))
```

---

**Update to simplify what I want to see as the end result**

Let's say I have dataA and dataB

```
dataA = [['2022-02-01', 123], ['2022-02-02', 120]]
dataB = [['2022-02-01', 123], ['2022-02-03', 125]]
```

I want to have

```
dataC = [['2022-02-01', 123], ['2022-02-02', 120], ['2022-02-03', 125]]
dfC = pd.DataFrame(dataC, columns = ['date', 'price'])
print(dfC)
```

Expected output

```
         name  price
0  2022-02-01    123
1  2022-02-02    120
2  2022-02-02    125
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to select rows based on a condition that is applied to the `index`.

Make the 'date' a proper column, and write a proper mask/condition, e.g.

```
relevant_data = data[data['date'] > pd.Timestamp.today()]
```

An explicit condition will allow you to control what you want (e.g., if you have a timestamp with second precision, but you want to match based on month/day accuracy, both `==` and `.loc` on index will not work, as you need to convert the column to day/month/hour first)

---

**UPDATE** regarding your edited question:
you can "combine" both dataframes into one, then remove duplicates (assuming that the price information from both dataframes is equal. if not, you will need to define the logic what price info should take precendence).

```
dfa = pd.DataFrame(dataA, columns=['date', 'price'])
dfb = pd.DataFrame(dataB, columns=['date', 'price'])
pd.concat([dfa, dfb]).drop_duplicates()
```

with output

```
         date  price
0  2022-02-01    123
1  2022-02-02    120
1  2022-02-03    125
```

Comment: Thanks, I've used the line above and for the date that doesn't exist, I get a result of "Empty DataFrame", the question is, how do I fetch this "Empty DataFrame" return so that I can insert a new data?

Comment: Well, what days would you like to have? It sounds like you want to fill "gaps" in a time series, but with what? You will need to define that, or have an exhaustive list of 'target' days that you need. All the ones that you **cannot** find will need to be created. But you cannot invert that logic: a missing record that shows `None` won't tell you what you are missing -> Create a list of all days that you want/need, populate the ones that you have with the data you have, the rest remains `NaN`

Comment: Correct I want to fill "gaps" in a time series. I'm going to append the data, and I know how to do looping to append each dates from the source array. However I first need to check if the data exist or not. Only for the dates that doesn't exist, I'll fill. I try to do `.index` or `.count` behind the dataframe, but it returns `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count'`

Comment: Start with your output taxonomy / all the days that you need. then do `pd.merge()` to get the existing data for the days that you know into that taxonomy. The rest will automatically remain `NaN`.. But that "output" (your own time axis), that is something you need to define separately/first. Its logic does not existing within your input data. -> "The `df` does not know what it does not know"

Comment: I've edited above to help you understand the end result of what I want to achieve. Please kindly check.

Comment: see updated reply

Comment: Awesome! Just learned about `.drop_duplicates()` thanks for the help!